# Do we need to download complete Android Studio if any updates

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I have Android Studio 3.0 Beta 7 and I want to update it to new version Android Studio 3.1 Canary.

It shows this dialog. Download button takes me to this page https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html?utm_source=android-studio and suggest to download complete IDE. Shouldn't it download updated patches ? or Is this for me only

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure, but by the time you finished posting this, you would have downloaded it :)

Comment: Beyond cricket_007's answer, bear in mind that usually you want to install a canary build *alongside* the current release build, so that show-stopper canary bugs don't impede your progress. Or, just stick with the release channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3.1 is a future release, which apparently isn't a patch for 3.0.

IntelliJ IDEA, which Android Studio is based on, does the same thing

And as @CommonsWare mentions, the Canary is pre-beta releases, so it's often used for those who want to use possible breaking changes.

---

The reason you downloaded 3.0 beta in the beginning was to get Kotlin, and whatever other changes, probably.

If that is the case, you can download 3.0 stable now.